# How to set javascript on a dynamic array?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a dynamic array inside a table which means the table appears based on user input. Users need to fill this table and then click submit. I need to place javascript here to check if the user didn't select anything or didn't write in any column. If so, the user should not be able to proceed.

```
<form action="klr.php"  method="post" name="myform"  >

     <?php

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $de; $i++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Tube</td>
            <td>
                <select id="in4-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="t1[<?php echo $i; ?>]" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onchange="getText39(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onmouseout="getText89(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="75">75</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="t2[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onchange="getText39(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onmouseout="getText89(<?php echo $i; ?>)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="a1[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="in2-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)"onchange="getText39(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onmouseout="getText89(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                     <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>

                </select>
            </td>
    </table>
```

I only provided the code of the first row of the table in which the user selects values. In the second column users can enter some values and in the third column users can select a value again. I need to place javascript in three of these columns

Comment: How does one simply place "java scripting"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure English isn't your first language, but I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're asking for. I assume you're asking for some sort of javascript client-side validation on your table?

Comment: yes i want client side javascripting if user not select any value or enter any value alert generate on submiting

Comment: @user2581292 if you know Urdu then let me know the problem, I will tell them in english.

Comment: So, have you looked at any javascript validations libraries at all? Have you even tried anything? I don't see any js code in your question, what code have you tried? What is the real issue here? No offence, but all I see is you wanting others to do your job.

Comment: plz ppl help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just wanted to verify if everything inside the form element was validated.  Here are two fiddles I worked up to get you started:

1) Regular Javascript

```
function formCheck() {
    var form = document.getElementById('mainForm'),
        inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'), 
        selects = form.getElementsByTagName('SELECT'),
        i,
        errors = [];


    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
            errors.push(inputs[i].title + ' was not set');
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        if (selects[i].selectedIndex === 0) {
            errors.push(selects[i].title + ' was not set');
        }
    }    

    if (errors.length > 0 ) {
        alert(errors.join('\n'));
        return false;
    } 
    alert('success!');
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/3Decx/4/

2) With JQuery

```
function formCheck() {
    var formElements = $('#mainForm').find('input, select'),
    errors = [];

    $.each(formElements, function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).val().match(/^\s*$/)) {
            errors.push($(el).prop('title') + ' is blank!');
        }
    });

    if (errors.length > 0 ) {
        alert(errors.join('\n'));
        return false;
    } 
    alert('success');
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/w5KG3/4/

A few notes: 1) It checks every input or select element inside a form element with id="mainForm" so you'd have to add that to your form (next to name="myForm"). 2) I added a title attribute to the input/select elements so I could show that in the error message as a reference. 3) It checks for whitespace in input boxes and consider that invalid. 4) in the jsFiddle, it returns false even in success so the form doesn't submit for demonstration purposes.  That should be changed to true if you use it.

Comment: where i get the jquery ?

Comment: how can i verify that user can only enter numerical value in input mean in text box

Comment: sir in some input mean textbox i have decimal value upto two decimal places its not considering that values

Comment: Then you change the Regex from \d+ which is an integer to \d+(.\d{1,2})?  which allows a decimal.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/w5KG3/6/

Comment: sir this not working for the hidden text box also they contain the numerical value n its also not picking select option in page but it works on js fiddle

Comment: sir i am using java scripting not j query kindly help me in that.

Comment: SO is a Q/A site.  Not a forum.  This is my last update.  http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/3Decx/5/  You really need to either learn  the code and modify it on your own or ask new questions.